# Nginx stream with upstream has same server but different port, get wired result

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $backend_name {
        home-s1.frp.xxx.com frp-s1;
        home-s2.frp.xxx.com frp-s2;
        default web;
    }

    upstream web {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }

    upstream frp-s1 {
        server internal-frps-s1.xxx.com:5011;
    }

    upstream frp-s2 {
        server internal-frps-s2.xxx.com:5014;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 reuseport;
        listen [::]:443 reuseport;
        proxy_pass  $backend_name;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

this is my Nginx conf, home-s1.frp.xxx.com and home-s2.frp.xxx.com have the same DNS record to 12.x.x.x, internal-frps-s1.xxx.com and internal-frps-s2.xxx.com are the same docker container with a different network alias

When I visit home-s1.frp.xxx.com, sometimes will get the HTML of home-s2.frp.xxx.com

This is so wired, home-s1.frp.xxx.com should get the service at port 5011's result, home-s1.frp.xxx.com should get the service at port 5014's result, how to make it work? Or must I use a reverse proxy?

Comment: have you tried using the ips directly?

Comment: no, with Docker, I have just try to assign a static IP to a container but failed

Comment: someone has exactly same issue with me, he thinks it because HTTP/2 and Wildcard cert https://www.orzlee.com/proxy/2021/04/13/nginx-sni-offload-port-multiplexing-uses-xray-vless-xtls.html

Comment: I am sorry my Japanese seems a bit outdated due my first language is german and the second english. I meaned,  home-s1.frp.xxx.com replace with the nativ ips of the docker ips instead using the hostnames - is this question business related?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it shouldn't be related to this issue, I'm basically sure it's due to some feature of HTTP/2, probably different from the different client implementations of HTTP/2, here is an English blogger's post to explain same issue https://levelup.gitconnected.com/multiplex-tls-traffic-with-sni-routing-ece1e4e43e56

Comment: Reverse_proxy dont handle http2 only http 1.0 and 1.1 - so it doenst matter - the frontend can handle http2 requests-  to take care that its not a resolving issue you should try ips.